# Python Error: Global Name not Defined

Tags: python, class

I'm trying to teach myself Python, and doing well for the most part. However, when I try to run the code

```
class Equilateral(object):
    angle = 60
    def __init__(self):
        self.angle1, self.angle2, self.angle3 = angle

tri = Equilateral()
```

I get the following error:

```
Traceback (most recent call last):
  File "python", line 15, in <module>
  File "python", line 13, in __init__
NameError: global name 'angle' is not defined
```

There is probably a very simple answer, but why is this happening?

Answer (score 8, accepted):

```
self.angle1, self.angle2, self.angle3 = angle
```

should be

```
self.angle1 = self.angle2 = self.angle3 = self.angle
```

just saying `angle` makes python look for a global `angle` variable which doesn't exist.  You must reference it through the `self` variable, or since it is a class level variable, you could also say `Equilateral.angle`

The other issues is your comma separated `self.angleN`s.  When you assign in this way, python is going to look for the same amount of parts on either side of the equals sign.  For example:

```
a, b, c = 1, 2, 3
```

Answer (score 4):

You need to use `self.angle` here because classes are namespaces in itself, and to access an attribute inside a class we use the `self.attr` syntax, or you can also use `Equilateral.angle` here as `angle` is a class variable too.

```
self.angle1, self.angle2, self.angle3 = self.angle
```

Which is still wrong becuase you can't assign a single value to three variables:

```
self.angle1, self.angle2, self.angle3 = [self.angle]*3
```

Example:

```
In [18]: x,y,z=1  #your version
---------------------------------------------------------------------------

TypeError: 'int' object is not iterable

#some correct ways:

In [21]: x,y,z=1,1,1  #correct because number of values on both sides are equal

In [22]: x,y,z=[1,1,1]  # in case of an iterable it's length must be equal 
                        # to the number elements on LHS

In [23]: x,y,z=[1]*3
```

Answer (score 0):

While a, b, c = d is invalid, a = b = c = d works just fine.