# Why am I getting a NameError when I try to access an attribute in my class?

Tags: python, python-2.7, class, attributes, nameerror

I have this code with a class:

```
class Triangle(object):
    def __init__(self, side1, side2, side3):
        self.side1 = side1
        self.side2 = side2
        self.side3 = side3

    def perimeter(self):
        return "Perimeter = %s" % (side1 + side2 + side3)

a = Triangle(3, 4, 5)
print(a.perimeter())
```

Running this code throws an exception:

```
Traceback (most recent call last):
  File "untitled.py", line 12, in <module>
    print(a.perimeter())
  File "untitled.py", line 9, in perimeter
    return "Perimeter = %s" % (side1 + side2 + side3)
NameError: name 'side1' is not defined
```

How come I can't access `side1` in the `perimeter` method?

Comment: `perimeter` method should be. `return "Perimeter = %s" %(self.side1 + self.side2 + self.side3)`

Comment: Another dupe target - https://stackoverflow.com/questions/16258199/python-error-global-name-not-defined

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Replace

```
return "Perimeter = %s" %(side1 + side2 + side3)
```

To

```
return "Perimeter = %s" %(self.side1 + self.side2 + self.side3)
```

You missed to add `self`

Answer (score 1):

This line:

```
return "Perimeter = %s" %(side1 + side2 + side3)
```

should be:

```
return "Perimeter = %s" %(self.side1 + self.side2 + self.side3)
```

To return the value of member variables in python, `self.` must be before the member. This is why self is one of the required parameters for member methods. In many other languages such as C#, the passing of `self` is implied, so you don't have to manually write it into the code.

Answer (score -1):

Unlike many other languages, python does not allow implicit access to instance attributes. To access an attribute in python, you must explicitly prefix it with `self.` like this:

```
return "Perimeter = %s" % (self.side1 + self.side2 + self.side3)
```

Without the `self.` prefix, python considers `side1` to be a local or global variable.

---

The same thing applies to methods. For example, if you wanted to call `perimeter` from `__init__`, this would not work:

```
def __init__(self, side1, side2, side3):
    self.side1 = side1
    self.side2 = side2
    self.side3 = side3

    perimeter()
```

Instead, you would have to write

```
self.perimeter()
```

See also [this related question](https://stackoverflow.com/q/4068785/1222951).